# Change the version of the C compiler used by RStan

Tags: r, gcc, environment-variables, rstan

I installed RStan on a machine running Scientific Linux 6.10.  Because the default GCC 4.4.7 is too old, I first installed devtoolkit 7, which provides GCC 7.3.1. The version is selected via the Environment Modules mechanism (which basically just tweaks the appropriate environment variables).

However, even though the environment set up to use GCC 7.4.1, when RStan runs and wants to compile stuff, it still tries to use the standard system GCC (I get an error message which includes paths to the old GCC version).

Is there some method akin to Makevars which I could use to ensure that the newer compiler is picked up?

Comment: I think the problem is that R will use the version of GCC it was compiled with.  It may well be possible to change this, but one solution is probably to recompile R with the newer version of GCC. I haven't got time to try this out at the moment, but I'll report back when I get round to it.

Comment: What is in your `~/.R/Makevars` file now?